# How to run python script at Ubuntu start?

Tags: boot, bash, python

I use free AWS instance running Ubuntu 14.04 and run python script there. I would like to have this python script started with each Ubuntu reboot, so I've edited `/etc/rc.local` and added the following lines there:

```
cd ~/myappfolder
while true; do timeout 1h python worker.py --log-level=ERROR; done
exit 0
```

But it doesn't work.
What could be wrong here?

Comment: /etc/rc.local doesn't work that way. It's used only for spawning other scripts.  Id suggest you make a wrapper script, save it somewhere, and call from rc.local as `/path/to/wrapper.sh &`

Comment: thanks, @Serg. AWS system log shows many `python: can't open file 'worker.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory` errors, when `cd ~/myappfolder` is first line of my `wrapper.sh` script. Manual run of `wrapper.sh` script works well and doesn't return this error. What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `crontab` for this.

```
cd ~/myappfolder while true; do timeout 1h python worker.py --log-level=ERROR; done exit 0
```

Create a .sh file and save it. (For example to /etc/myscript.sh) Test run it. If you get a **Permission Denied** error run `chmod +x /etc/myscript.sh`

Then run these commands:

```
crontab -e
@reboot /etc/myscript.sh
```

Those commands insert the last line into crontab so it runs everytime you reboot.

Comment: Thanks. Do I need to have `exit 0` at my script?

Comment: @LA_ Yes. `exit 0`terminates the shell script with a success message. (For more information you can check out https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Exit_command )

Comment: Thanks. How could I verify that it works? Python script doesn't generate any output. I tried to use `logger "ok"`, but it doesn't work since AWS doesn't write everything to system log.

Comment: @LA_ I'd recommend checking this link https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html